# Chef reports tab search by node?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

This might be a feature of Chef Automate, but I'm not ready to purchase yet so need a solution for this with the free license.

In the GUI the Reports tab is pretty limited. I can go to run history and filter by date and status but can't search by node. Is there a knife command or something where I could return the status of a single nodes run history?

Comment: AFAIK Automate is available under the same demo license (i.e. free demo for <=25 nodes) as Manage and Reporting. Even if it isn't, it's a proprietary product so people outside of Chef Software are unlikely to have much knowledge of internals and customizations. You can reach Chef Software support at support@chef.io

Comment: Thanks for the info, but regardless of that I'd prefer a simple scripty solution for now without adding to my infrastructure. Your saying I'd have to hack it to get what I want here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_reporting.html#runs-show is the relevant knife plugin, but for building a dashboard I would probably grab `chef-api` (for Ruby) or `PyChef` (for Python) and use the API directly.